# Sagemaker doesn't inference in an async manner

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I've deployed a custom model with an async endpoint. I want to process video files with it because videos can have ~5-10 minutes I can't load all frames to memory. Of course, I want to make an inference on each frame.
I've written
`input_fn` - download video file from s3 using boto and creates generator which loads video frames with a given batch size - return a generator - written with OpenCV
`predict_fn` - iterate over generator batched frames and generate prediction using model - save prediction in list
`output_fn` - transform prediction into json format, gzip all to reduce the size

Endpoint works well, but the problem is concurrency. The sagemaker endpoint processes request after request (from cloudwatch and s3 save file time). I don't know why this happens.
max_concurrent_invocations_per_instance is set to 1000. Other settings from PyTorch serving are as follows:

```
SAGEMAKER_MODEL_SERVER_TIMEOUT: 100000
SAGEMAKER_TS_MAX_BATCH_DELAY: 10000
SAGEMAKER_TS_BATCH_SIZE: 1000
SAGEMAKER_TS_MAX_WORKERS: 4
SAGEMAKER_TS_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT: 100000
```

And still, it doesn't work. So how can I create an async inference endpoint with PyTorch to get concurrency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concurrency settings for TorchServe DLC are controlled by such mechanisms as # of workers, which can be set by defining the appropriate variables, such as `SAGEMAKER_TS_*`, and `SAGEMAKER_MODEL_*` (see, e.g., [this page](https://github.com/pytorch/serve/blob/master/docs/configuration.md) for details on their meaning and implications).

While the latter are agnostic to any particular serving stack and are defined in the [SageMaker Inference Toolkit](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-inference-toolkit), the former are TorchServe-specific and are defined in [TorchServe Inference Toolkit](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-pytorch-inference-toolkit). Moreover, since the TorchServe Inference Toolkit is built on top of the SageMaker Inference Toolkit, there is a non-trivial interplay between these two sets of params.

Thus you may also want to experiment with such params as, e.g., `SAGEMAKER_MODEL_SERVER_WORKERS` to properly set up the concurrency setting of the SageMaker Async Endpoint.

Comment: Thank you very much it works! I've set up SAGEMAKER MODEL SERVER WORKERS to maximum and seems sagemaker running concurrently.